# How to load config file in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, configuration

I use Jenkins for building my program. The steps for reproduce my problem are as follows:

1. Write Jenkins job
2. Save it
3. Copy Jenkins generated .xml file into another path

I can not load `config.xml` file. Is there a special command for loading in Jenkins?

**Update:**

We copied `/var/lib/jenkins/job/ProjectName/config.xml` into `/var/lib/jenkins/job/NewProjectName/config.xml`, but the NewProject is not shown in Jenkins. We have specified the `JENKINS_HOME` path for other directory and we are not getting any results.

Comment: Be more specific. From which path did you copied and to which path did you pasted ?

Comment: We copied /var/lib/jenkins/job/ProjectName/config.xml indo /var/lib/jenkins/job/NewProjectName/config.xml

The NewProject is not shown in Jenkins.
And we have specified JENKINS_HOME path for other directory and we are not got any results.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell Jenkins to "Reload Configuration from Disk". This can be found under "Manage Jenkins". Or, re-start Jenkins.

If all you want to do is create a copy of an existing job, click on "New item" and enter the name of the existing job at the bottom where it says "If you want to create a new item from other existing, you can use this option:"

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work. Have another way for load config.xml file?

Comment: @Astine Restarting Jenkins did not work? I sometimes move jobs from one jenkins to another by copying the job directory to the new jenkins and then having it reload.

Comment: Yes, I copied /var/lib/jenkins/job/ProjectName/config.xml into /var/lib/jenkins/job/NewProjectName/config.xml, Then clicked  "Reload Configuration from Disk", under "Manage Jenkins". But haven't gotten  good result. The NewProject does not added in Jenkins interface. Does this steps correct?

Comment: @Astine On my Jenkins server, the name of the directory containing all of the jobs is called "jobs". You are using "job". All of the Jenkins servers that I've managed use "jobs", not "job". Maybe there's a configuration option that I don't know about. Or, maybe you are using the wrong directory. What version of Jenkins are you using?

Comment: I using  2.102 version of Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

Use REST API instead of making changes in files.

Get config from existing job:

`curl -X GET http://<your_jenkins_url>/job/test/config.xml -u username:API_TOKEN -o mylocalconfig.xml`

Create/Update job:

`curl -s -XPOST 'http://<your_jenkins_url>/createItem?name=yourJobName' -u username:API_TOKEN --data-binary @mylocalconfig.xml -H "Content-Type:text/xml"`

And you shouldn't restart Jenkins in this case or reread config files from file system.

Answer (score 0):

I think modifying jobs config manually is a bad idea.

I suggest you use [Jenkins Job DSL](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin) plugin or [Jenkins Job Builder](https://docs.openstack.org/infra/jenkins-job-builder/) to create new / modify existing jobs.

Comment: But I want to load already existed config.xml file  in Jenkins. Can  DSL plugin help me for this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure what the OP is ultimately after, but manually creating jobs is a useful capability. I have Jenkins jobs that create new Jenkins jobs.

Comment: @Astine you can describe your job using Job DSL language and it will be equal job in your config.xml

Also I remembered one method. You can send POST request to your Jenkins with job XML config as data. URL will be like
http://my-cool-jenkins.com:8080/createItem?name=mycooljob